# Tensorflow is installed and Tensorflow hub is installed still getting error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have been googling and doing everything I have read about this issue and it seems it will not work and I cant figure it out.
Here is the issue:[Tensorflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvZf5.png)

I have made sure that hub is installed and it is:
[Tensorflow hub installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXXU2.png)

This should be working and it keeps erroring out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating tensor flow.

```
$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow      # for Python 2.7
$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n
```

This may depend on what code editor you are using and what interoperator or package installer you are using. I think sometimes you might have to uninstall python. I am familiar with anaconda and I have had this problem but upgrading the module most of the time worked.

Its usually because there are multiple instalations or versions of python on the environment.

Comment: I tried that as well, it is fully updated still getting the error

Comment: What IDE or editor are you using

Comment: the pycharm IDE

Comment: At this point If you're having problems, I would uninstall and reinstall all instances of python including the ide or package. There are definitely multiple packages being saved in the same environment.                                                                                     
If you want to I would recommend using anaconda, you can still launch pycharm through it but you can manage the modules and set up the environments easily.

Comment: Anaconda is more preferred over pycharm?

Comment: You can launch pycharm through anaconda. I just find it really easy to set up an environment and manage modules in anaconda.